# Definition Sigma Algebra generated by random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I know the Sigma Algebra generated by a random variable $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \to (I, \mathcal{A})$, can be defined as $\{ Y \in \mathcal{F} \mid \exists B \in \mathcal{A}(Y = X^{-1}(B)) \}$. However, I think my professor has somewhat implicitly mentioned that when I is a countable space, and $\mathcal{A} = P(I)$, the generated Sigma Algebra is $\sigma(\cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \{ X =i \})$, where $\{ X = i\}$ is all the s in $\Omega$ s.t $X(s) = i$

This is what I recalled of how he defined it as he never really write down the exact definition, and I'm not sure if it's even true or not. If it is, I cannot really see why would these two definition coincide, as the latter is not really considering all event. I guess it might be true in the case of I is a countable space, but I doubt it would be true in general. So are these definitions equal in this case, and in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a bit thrown by your use of $\Sigma$, so I'm using $\Upsilon$ (and the lower case $\upsilon$) instead.

---

Let $\Upsilon$ be a countable set, and let $\mathcal A = \mathcal P(\Upsilon)$ be the power set $\sigma$-algebra. If $S = \left\{ \{ \upsilon \} \colon \upsilon \in \Upsilon\right\} \subset \mathcal{P}(\Upsilon)$, then $\sigma(S) = \mathcal{A}$. In particular, $\mathcal{A}$ can be generated from $S$ via countable unions.

As you know, $\sigma(X) = \left\{ X^{-1}(A) \colon A \in \mathcal{A} \right\}$. Using certain properties of inverse images, we have

\begin{align*}
X^{-1}(A) &= X^{-1}\left( \bigcup_{\upsilon \in A} \{ \upsilon \} \right) = \bigcup_{\upsilon \in A} X^{-1}\left( \{ \upsilon \} \right)
\end{align*}

This implies that $\sigma(X) = \sigma\left(\left\{ X^{-1}(\upsilon) \colon \upsilon \in \Upsilon \right\}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have upvoted it. I understand the bulk, but before accepting it, would you mind helping me clarify a few details? (1) What is {v}? I am new to this, and I saw many places where people just surrounds event with curly braces like X = v to {X = v} what's the point of doing so? (2) Does this apply in general when it's not countable, and the event space is not the power set?

Comment: (1) $\{ \upsilon \}$ (lower case upsilon; just a Greek letter I chose) is the singleton set containing upsilon. It's just a set containing one element. Strictly speaking, events are sets, so something like $P(X > 1)$ is more properly written $P(\{X > 1\})$, but the former is just shorthand. (2) This does not work in general. If we work with the identity function $X \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, using the Borel sigma algebra on both sides, then $\sigma(X)$ is the Borel sigma algebra, but the sigma algebra generated by preimages of singletons is the countable-cocountable sigma algebra.

Comment: @wsz_fantasy I ran out of room to tag you in my reply above.

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept it right now. One quick thing do you mean $X^{-1}(\{v\})$ in the last line?

Comment: @wsz_fantasy Yes, I think I goofed there

Comment: I see. Btw, I was originally wondering about the Sigma Algebra generated by multiple random variables. I assume it is the sigma field generated by the union of the sigma field generated by each random variable. Can it also be simplified into something in this case?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, and I think site guidelines would encourage you to ask a separate question, if you have one.

Comment: I have asked the new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4637473/sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-set-of-random-variables-when-countable?)