# Sigma algebra generated by a set of random variables when countable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have previously asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636194/definition-sigma-algebra-generated-by-random-variables), and this question is just a generalization

> For a set of random variable $X_{s} :(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \to (I, P(I)), s\in S$, where I is a countable set. Is the sigma-algebra generated by this set of random variables $\sigma(\{ \{ X_{1} = i_{1}, X_{2} = i_{2}, \dots, X_n = i_{n}\}\mid i_{1}, i_{2},\dots i_{n} \in I\})$(Here we assume S is a finite set)? Would this generalize to S that is countable, or even to any set of S?

Even in the finite case, I am too sure whether it is true. With some algebraic manipulations, I get to $$\sigma\left(\bigcap_{1\leq s \leq n}\bigcup_{i \in I}\{ X_{s} = i \}\right)$$ is in the set. But I don't know how to proceed further.

Also, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039896/sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-set-of-random-variables) for the definition of sigma-algebra generated by a set of random variables. It is the smallest subset of $\mathcal{F}$ that makes all these random variables measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is true if $S$ is finite, but not otherwise. If $S = \{1, \dots, n\}$, then

$$
\sigma(\{X_s \in A\}: s \in S, A \subseteq I)=\sigma(\{X_1=i_1, \dots, X_n=i_n\}:i_1, \dots, i_n \in I).$$

You can prove this by showing that both sides include each other; LHS $\subseteq$ RHS because $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable union, and RHS $\subseteq$ LHS because $\sigma$-algebras are closed under finite intersection.

However, for $S = \{1, 2, \dots\},$ take $I = \{0, 1\},$ $\Omega = I^S$, and $X_s(\omega) = \omega_s$. Then

$$\sigma(\{X_1=i_1, X_2=i_2, \dots\}:i_1, i_2, \ldots \in I)$$

contains only sets which are countable or have countable complement, so is not equal to $\sigma(X_s:s\in S)$. (You can prove this using the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have given you an upvote. Before accepting your answer, can you elaborate on why LHS $\subseteq$ RHS?.

Comment: Any set $\{X_s \in A\}$ can be written as a countable union of sets $\{X_1=i_n, \dots, X_n=i_n\}$; hence anything in the LHS can be generated by sets in the RHS. @wsz_fantasy

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking, why can any set $\{X_{s} \in {A} \}$ be written as a countable union of sets $\{X_1=i_n, \dots, X_n=i_n\}$

Comment: $\{X_s \in A\} = \cup_{i_1, \dots, i_n \in I, i_s \in A}\{X_1=i_1, \dots, X_n=i_n\}$, which is a countable union as $I$ is countable. @wsz_fantasy

Comment: Ah, just fixed a typo in the answer, sorry if that was confusing you! @wsz_fantasy